# How to conditionally subtract from a value

Tags: python

I'm running Python 3.7.4 and I noticed some undesireable behavior while working on something, which I then reduced to this:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> x -= 1 if False else print("blah")
blah
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Unless there's something obvious I'm just missing? Why is it even trying to eval the -= if it's fallen through to the else?

Comment: no. `x + None` should raise an error. If you had written `x -= 1 if <condition> else 5`, you'd expect `x -= 5` to happen at some point

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but why x + None? it should only decrement x if the statement evals to true right? So why if we're hitting the false case is it even evaluating the -=?
Should just print "blah"?

Comment: x-=print('blah') doesn't work. If it's true the expression works, if it's false you're telling it to do something that doesn't work.

Comment: ah, gotcha.  I'm thinking about this inline if wrong.

Comment: This `if`-`else` is a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), not a [conditional statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Comment: Yep. Got it now thanks. Python newbie.

Comment: The answer to "is this a bug in the language" is almost always NO.

Comment: :-D In my heart of hearts I knew that.

Comment: Well, python newbie reborn, since I haven't touched it for a while to be exact...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you do ternary expressions in Python. You can do it like this:

```
x = (x-1 if False else print('foo'))
```

Only thing to keep in mind, this will set `x=None` since that is what the print statement returns.

If you mean to set `x` to the string `foo`, this will work

```
x=(x-1 if False else 'foo')
```

Or, as @PaulH suggested, x is to remain unchanged:

```
x=(x-1 if False else x and print('foo') or x)
```

doing that last one might not be the clearest way of doing this, but it works:

```
>>> x=5
>>> x=(x-1 if False else x and print('foo') or x)
foo
>>> x
5
>>> x=(x-1 if True else x and print('foo') or x)
>>> x
4
```

Comment: that will assign `None` to the variable `x`, which I doubt the OP wants.

Comment: @PaulH I can't really see anything else that OP might be after in this case, besides setting x to None.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP wants to substract 1 from x if a condition is met. If that condition is not met, the value of x should remain unchanged

Comment: Thanks all for the time and help.

Comment: Really, none of these alternatives is an improvement over a simple `if/else` statement.

Comment: @chepner The first 2 aren't necessarily worse, either. The last one is definitely hokey though. But this is how the question was posed.

Comment: The OP was clearly trying to use the conditional expression to execute *either* `x -= 1` or `print("blah")`.  Not assign the return value of `print` to `x`, or to assign the string `"foo"` to `x`. The last one has the desired semantics, but is, frankly, an abomination.

Comment: @chepner There's not enough regular expressions for the last one to be an abomination.

Answer (score 5):

This is grouped as:

```
(x) -= (1 if False else print("blah"))
```

Not:

```
(x -= 1) if False else (print("blah"))
```

Although since `-=` and other assignment statements don't themselves evaluate to a value, they can't appear as a part of a conditional expression. The left and right-hand arguments to the assignment [are evaluated separately, then assigned to the left-hand argument](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements):

> An augmented assignment evaluates the target [`x`] . . . and the expression list [`1 if False else print("blah")`], performs the binary operation specific to the type of assignment on the two operands [`-`], and assigns the result to the original target.

The conditional expression on the right evaluates to `None` (because `print` returns `None`), then you attempt to subtract the resulting `None` from `x`.

Comment: Can u please explain, how `(1 if False else print("blah"))` gives none ?

Comment: @VishalKamlapure `(1 if condition else print("blah"))` evaluates to `1` if the `condition` is truthy, and `print("blah")` if it's falsey. Since you have the condition as `False`, `(1 if False else print("blah"))` evaluates to `print("blah")`, which evaluates to `None`, since that's what `print` returns.

Comment: Conditional expressions are used to produce one of two values based on a condition. They aren't intended to conditionally do something (like conditionally do an assignment).

Comment: @VishalKamlapure maybe you can get some inspiration from [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/5987).

Comment: You should make clear that `x -= 1` is not an expression, and so cannot be part of a conditional expression, so explicit parentheses would not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do what you're after:

```py
if <condition>:
    x -= 1
```

or

```py
x -= 1 if <condition> else 0
```

In the first case, if the condition is met, 1 will be subtracted from `x`. Otherwise, no operation is performed on the value of `x`.

In the second case, some value is always subtracted from `x`. When the condition is met, that value is 1, otherwise it is 0 (effectively a no-op for the value of `x`).

Comment: it's definitely not a no-op, because `<condition>` could easily have side effect: `a=[5]; x-=(1 if a.append(100) else 0)`

Comment: @Z4-tier that's fair, but I think pretty beyond the scope of the OP's situation. In your example, it's still a no-op as far the value of `x` is concerned

Comment: interestingly, I can't actually come up with anything that will make `dis.dis()` output a true `NOP` operation (opcode 9). None of `pass`, `0`, `True`, `None`, `False`, `exit()`, `1*1`. I get what you mean for the purpose of this question/answer, but now I'd really like to know what will generate an opcode 9 operation. I guess that is a good question in itself.

Comment: @Z4-tier that's very interesting! I admit I was using the term loosely.